# Implicitly Typed Array of Methods Generates Error CS0826

Tags: c#

I am using C# with Visual Studio Community 2022. This line of code compiles fine:

```
int[] i = new[] { 0 };
```

This line also compiles fine:

```
System.Action[] a = new System.Action[] { () => { } };
```

However, this line generates error CS0826, "No best type found for implicitly-typed array:"

```
System.Action[] a = new[] { () => { } };
```

I had expected the compiler to be able to infer the type. Indeed, all of the lines above compile without error in LINQPad 7.

Any assistance in understanding why Visual Studio 2022 reports an error (and LINQPad 7 does not)  would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What version of C# are you using - it compiles for me without error.

Comment: im not getting errors on Net 7, the initialized value for a is {System.Action[1]} with[0] equals to: {Method = {Void <<Main>$>b__0_3()}}

Comment: It compiles on **.Net 6**, but not on **.Net 5** - https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPRkr7

Comment: A fiddle also compiles and runs https://dotnetfiddle.net/qcvi2K

Comment: @SBFrancies I'm using 7.3 in VS2022. I haven't been able to get the version for LINQPad 7, though they say it has all "C# 10 features," so I'd infer at least version 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because of your version of C#. I am not able to compile this with the same error in earlier versions but in C# 10 I can.

The expression that you defined in your array does not have a type until it is cast to Func, Action or Expression. As of C# 10 you can infer delegate types which allows a best type to be found for that implicitly typed array.

So the reason that this doesn't compile:

`System.Action[] a = new[] { () => { } };`

is because prior to C# 10 this also does not compile:

`var a = () => { };`

because prior to C# 10 that did not yet have a type to choose.

Comment: By gosh, that appears to be the reason. Indeed, this will also compile in C# 10: `var a = new[] { () => { } };`, albeit only inside a method. Thanks!